# How to augment the Vue class and keep typescript definition in sync

Tags: vue.js

I'm extending the default Vue object with

```
export default (Vue) => {
  Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $http: {
      get () {
        return axiosInstance
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I'm using typescript and of course typescript doesn't like this.
How can i create a project specific .d.ts file in such a way the vue typescript declaration is augmented with the above extension?

Answer (score 12):

There is now excellent documentation regarding this on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins:

> **Augmenting Types for Use with Plugins**
>
> Plugins may add to Vue’s global/instance properties and component
> options. In these cases, type declarations are needed to make plugins
> compile in TypeScript. Fortunately, there’s a TypeScript feature to
> augment existing types called module augmentation.
>
> For example, to declare an instance property $myProperty with type
> string:
>
> ```
> // 1. Make sure to import 'vue' before declaring augmented types
> import Vue from 'vue'
>
> // 2. Specify a file with the types you want to augment
> //    Vue has the constructor type in types/vue.d.ts
> declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
>   // 3. Declare augmentation for Vue
>   interface Vue {
>     $myProperty: string
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> After including the above code as a declaration file (like
> my-property.d.ts) in your project, you can use $myProperty on a Vue
> instance.
>
> ```
> var vm = new Vue()
> console.log(vm.$myProperty) // This should compile successfully
> ```
>
> You can also declare additional global properties and component
> options:
>
> ```
> import Vue from 'vue'
>
> declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
>   // Global properties can be declared
>   // on the `VueConstructor` interface
>   interface VueConstructor {
>     $myGlobal: string
>   }
> }
>
> // ComponentOptions is declared in types/options.d.ts
> declare module 'vue/types/options' {
>   interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
>     myOption?: string
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The above declarations allow the following code to be compiled:
>
> ```
> // Global property
> console.log(Vue.$myGlobal)
>
> // Additional component option
> var vm = new Vue({
>   myOption: 'Hello'
> })
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Create a file with following content:

```
import {AxiosStatic} from 'axios';


declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  export interface Vue   {
    $http: AxiosStatic;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the file name, and where it needs to be placed ??? :-(