# How to Properly Register axios Globally in Vue & TypeScript Application

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

I've been fighting with Vue, TypeScript and Axios and I cannot arrive at what feels like a satisfactory solution.

Most guides will tell you to do this:

**Main.ts**

```
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

And then use the $http.  TypeScript doesn't like this:

> Property '$http' does not exist on type CombinedVueInstance

How can I register axios globally and avoid any TypeScript errors?

Based on @GentlemanCrow answer below I created a file in my root directory called:

axios-plugin.d.ts

```
import _Vue from 'vue';
import Axios from 'axios';

export function AxiosPlugin<AxiosPlugOptions>(Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: AxiosPluginOptions): void {
    // do stuff with options
    Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;
}

export class AxiosPluginOptions {
    // add stuff
}

import { AxiosStatic } from 'axios';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $http: AxiosStatic;
    }
}
```

This produces the error:

(TS) An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.

And on `Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;` the error is:

Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.

Removing the `export function AxiosPlugin` function and attempting to execute a request errors with:

> TypeError: "this.$http is undefined"

Where should the following code go?

```
export function AxiosPlugin<AxiosPlugOptions>(Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: AxiosPluginOptions): void {
    // do stuff with options
    Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to register it as a typescript declaration file - so create a separate file called 'axios-plugin.d.ts' and put in:

```
import _Vue from 'vue';
import Axios from 'axios';

export function AxiosPlugin<AxiosPlugOptions>(Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: AxiosPluginOptions): void {
    // do stuff with options
    Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;
}

export class AxiosPluginOptions {
    // add stuff
}

import { AxiosStatic } from 'axios';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $http: AxiosStatic;
    }
}
```

then you should have access to `Vue.$http` where you need it.

`Vue.prototype.$http = axios;` would work in pure javascript but Typescript forces you to declare everything BUT you get that sweet, sweet type checking.

You can see some more general info on definition files here, along with an Axios example: [How to augment the Vue class and keep typescript definition in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142304/how-to-augment-the-vue-class-and-keep-typescript-definition-in-sync/43232151#43232151)

Comment: Thanks, have tried this approach and still having a few issues. Will investigate.

Comment: I can't figure out where to put this code to get this working. Can you have a look at my updated question?

Comment: Here's another way - this project vue-axios (https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios) will give you a global `Vue.axios` variable.The repo is really only two files (index.d.ts and src/index.ts), so if you wanted to re-implement it yourself and get a `Vue.$http` instead, you could.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can create a global Axios instance in your Vue 3 TypeScript application:

First, install Axios using npm or yarn:

```
npm install axios
```

Next, create a new file (e.g. axios.ts) to configure your Axios instance:

```
    import axios from 'axios';

    // Create a new Axios instance
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://api.example.com',
      timeout: 5000,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    // Add a request interceptor
    instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      // Do something before the request is sent
      return config;
    }, error => {
      // Do something with request error
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    // Add a response interceptor
    instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      // Do something with response data
      return response;
    }, error => {
      // Do something with response error
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    export default instance;
```

In your Vue 3 TypeScript components, you can import the Axios instance and use it to make API requests:

```
import axios from '@/axios';

export default {
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/data');
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  },
};
```

By using this approach, you can reuse the same Axios instance across all of your components and make consistent API requests with shared settings and interceptors.